# PyMongo Update Dict Value of Key inside List

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am trying to update a dict value inside a list but it's resetting the other keys too.

For example,

```
data = {"a": "1", "b": "2", "c": ["d": "3", "e": "4", "f": "5"]}
```

but when I am doing:

```
mongo_collection.update_one({"a": "1"}, {"$set": {"a": "2", "c": ["d": "7"]})
```

My dict changes to:

```
{"a": "2", "b": "2", "c": ["d": "7"]}
```

Comment: `"c": ["d": "7"]` in the update statement is updating the field `c`. You need to try to update the `c` the _array_ data type field.

Comment: @prasad_ how can I do that? Indexing ?

Comment: This is the place to start: [Array Update Operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/reference/operator/update/index.html#array).

Comment: the nested list should not have column or  **:**

Answer (score 0):

Your nested list contains columns which results in invalid syntax.

Otherwise you can follow this approach

```
data = {"a": "1", "c": ["d", "3", "e", "4"]}

data["c"][1] = "49"

print(data)
```

output

```
{"a": "1", "c": ["d", "49", "e", "4"]}
```

Comment: My query is on MongoDB, how can I achieve the output using pymongo.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_mongodb_getstarted.asp